# jsonObject.getString("String in UTF8" ) giving blank

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, utf-8

I am fetching a string from my MySql DB on and online server using webservice in JSON format.
I am able to see that Android Studio is fetching it correctly as I see it in debugging mode.
But when I go ahead and add it to a List list, I get nothing.

Here's some more info:
What I am getting:

```
{"products":[{"veg_name_eng":"Corn","veg_name_hindi":"मक्का"}],"success":1}
```

My concern is with: "veg_name_hindi":"मक्का"

When I go ahead and try to put it in a dataitem list, I get nothing:

```
public static List<DataItem> dataItemList;
dataItemList.add(jsonObject.getString(veg_name_eng),jsonObject.getString(veg_name_hindi))
```

veg_name_eng and veg_name_hindi are the column names at my table.

After the above code I get dataItemList = null, So nothing is adding to it.

In my server side MySql DB, I am using UTF-8 encoding.

I am using android studio.

**UPDATE 1:**

I am parsing the JSON as :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myJSONString);
veg_list = jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");
try {
    while (TRACK < veg_list.length()) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = veg_list.getJSONObject(TRACK);
        addItem(new DataItem(jsonObject.getString(veg_name_eng), jsonObject.getString(veg_name_hindi)));
        TRACK = TRACK + 1;
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

// and the addItem function is as follows:

```
private static void addItem(DataItem item) {
    dataItemList.add(item); //While Debugging, I can see that value of item is correct. (i.e., item: DataItem{veg_name_eng='Cork', veg_name_hindi='मक्का'} )
    dataItemMap.put(item.getVeg_id(), item);
}
```

Comment: Did you [check for json_encode errors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/617/json/2637/debugging-json-errors)?

Comment: I checked it just now, There's no error, the php script at online DB is running fine and returning correct o/p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Make a model of the your JSON String using

http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/

and then map your JSON String to your Model using **Gson**. It's much easy to use.

Another way to get your required String for this particular result is parse json string yourself.

For Example :

```
String vegNameEng,vegNameHindi;

vegNameEng = vegNameHindi = "";

try{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("products");
    vegNameEng = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("veg_name_eng");
    vegNameHindi = arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("veg_name_hindi");
}catch(JSONException ex){

}
```

Now vegNameEng and vegNameHindi have the required data.

Comment: I was already using a model for my JSON string, I created a class called DataItem.java for that. Will try Gson..

Comment: Give it a try. You will get it. or Try the alternative solution. Just use the above code with yourJsonString and you will have your data in the respective fields.

Comment: Also, @Umer-Farooq I have been parsing json in the similar way.. For details please check the Update 1 in the main thread (which I just added.)

Comment: Just put a debug point at try block and check that it is either going through the loop or not .. I hope so that the value of TRACK is initially 0.

Comment: It's solved now, the problem was completely different then what I thought. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, It was a silly mistake, the variable I was using to put data into the database was overwritten by some other variable with the same name. Closing the thread for now. Thanks @Umer-Farooq.